# How to handle the dynamic growth in length of divs

Tags: html, css, loops

I am looping through an array of products. I am displaying one next to the other, but some products have more characters in the name than others. So the result is that some `'product blocks'` are higher than the other blocks. I would like to keep the same height for all of them.

Here is an image of my problem:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($random_products as $random_product) {

    $product_image = unserialize($random_product['images']);

    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo '<img src="'.$product_image[0].'" alt="'.$random_product['name'].'" title="'.$random_product['name'].'">';

    echo '<p>'.$random_product['name'].'</p>';

    if($random_product['on_special'] == '1'){
        echo '<p>From R'.$random_product['special_price'].'</p><br>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>From R'.$random_product['price'].'</p><br>';
    }

    echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pop-prod-btn">View Product</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Here you need to give a fixed height to keep all in same heights or you can apply a limit on the text string.

Comment: Try this in CSS: `.item{   heigth: 5rem; } // for example`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I add a min-height, max-height and height auto to the class item ?

Comment: http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/an-equal-height-grid-using-flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use following code samples  to over come this issue:

PHP/HTML:

```
echo '<div class="prdt-title"> <p>'.$random_product['name'].'</p> </div>';
```

CSS:

```
.prdt-title{
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;  
    white-space: nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.prdt-title p{
    overflow: hidden;  
    white-space: nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will keep your box height fixed for all items in box and hide extra characters that will over flow from the box.